# Laravel shows 404 after changing in sessions

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, inertiajs

I am facing a strange issue. I am force longing in the user and setting some information in the session. After that, I am seeing 404. there is nothing in the logs and I am not sure what is happening

```
public function index($userId)
{
    $users = UserRelation::where('relation_user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->pluck('relation_user_id')->toArray();

    if (in_array($userId, $users)) {
        if (empty(Session::get('original_user'))) {
            Session::put('original_user', Auth::user());
            Auth::loginUsingId($userId);
            Session::put('is_logged_in_as_delegate', true);
            return Inertia::location(route('index'));

        } else {
            dd('in here');
        }
    }

    abort(403);
}
```

Comment: what happens if you comment this line : `return Inertia::location(route('index'));` ?

Comment: Still shows 404, but this works without the session changes. Redirects without an error

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, just an FYI :) You can use the [exists()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist) method with the query builder/Eloquent to simplify your check: `$exists = UserRelation::where('relation_user_id', Auth::id())->exists()`.

Answer (score 0):

try `Auth::logout();` before `Auth::loginUsingId($userId);`